# Setting up USSD development environment for testing and developing a USSD based service before deployment

Tags: sms, jboss7.x, sms-gateway, ussd

I've looked over the internet for a long time but failed to find the information about setting up an environment for developing and testing USSD services on my PC.

I need a web-based application that uses RESP API for sending requests and which go to the USSD server which forwards them to the GSM phone. How can i start developing this?

Answer (score 1):

This is not something that is as easy as it seems at first glance.

I worked on a project out in the middle east some time ago where we had this exact requirement, and we actually had to enlist the help of the local telco company to support our efforts.

Essentially it's all down to the way SMS in general works.

Most people think that SMS is sent in a byte orientated fashion over an 8 bit channel much like MMS and GPRS data is, but in fact it's not.

SMS is actually sent on the signalling channel of most GSM based devices (Which is why your SMS doesn't work when the phone is ringing for example)

More so, only a fraction of this signalling channel is used and it's often out of band serial data.

Given that info, at a very minimum you'd need a local GSM connection that was addressable using a standard msisdn (thats the real name for a phone number), that connection would then have to provide a standard C7 signalling environment that could be reacted to and the serial data decoded, before being pushed into an SMPP based server (or similar) at the connection end.

Once you had the decoded message in the server, and you'd analyzed the various flags in the PDU for the message to know that it's a USSD message, you'd then need to remove the message from the queue, process it, figure out what the command meant, then send it to an application server that would then decide what URL to call, or what soap endpoint to pass it to and many other factors, as well as taking any response, converting it back to SMPP then re-serializing it and sending it back down the signalling channel to the original device.

Now, with the correct know how and equipment, it's certainly possible to set your own up.  Many mobile phone providers these days will provide their customers with pico cells in poor coverage areas, it's also possible to buy stub antennas that can be hooked to a local PC but you need to be absolutely sure that your allowed to do that in your area.

Many authorities strictly control what radio emissions are and are not allowed in any given area, and heavy fines or imprisonment will be the outcome to those who break those laws.

Once you have an antenna, then you can run something like 'Open BTS' on the machine the antenna is connected too.  Open BTS does everything that a standard GSM networks BTS software does, including passing data upstream from the aBis interface right through to things like the SMPP servers used for SMS traffic.

It does not however provide SMS software, for that you would need another machine with a standard Linux distro on it, then software such as Kannel setting up and running on it, once you have kannel, then you have the ability to process messages.

Make all of this work together, and you'll be able to do local USSD testing.

there is a much easier alternative however, but it's likely to cost you some money, and that's to sign up with a service provider such as global USSD ( [Link Here](http://globalussd.com/service-development-account/) ) or similar who for a fixed fee will do all the hard work for you, leaving you to concentrate on responding to your app calls.

Answer (score 0):

All need is a service provider (API from a Telcom provider such as MTN, Orange etc ) and secondly, you will have to just create endpoints to which callbacks may be made to.  languages such as python, Php and Nodejs currently support ussd application development.

Remember that Ussd is a session-based application and the way it works is sort of one way. This means that you will have to structure you business logic to fit your user needs and make them feel they are using it like a web app or mobile app

lastly, the callback can be hosted on any cloud-hosted service such as Heroku, Google cloud platform or AWs and that URL is the callback but in case you want to try  out from local machine you may install tools like ngrok(https://ngrok.com/) or vagrant(https://www.vagrantup.com/) to make localhost have a public address and use that public address as your callback